# Pushing single changes using phpstorm / git repository

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm new to using git repositories and phpstorm, i've only been using this for a few months at most.

I'm wanting to know how to push single/specific commits. For example, I made changes to a few files, I've committed those files, and when I go to push those files through phpstorm, it wants to push multiple other commits/changes to the repository as well. I only want to push the single commit I just made though, not the other changes I made before this. So now i'm stuck with a push that I can't actually push yet, and I don't think I can even modify it. I guess my main question is: **Why can I choose what I want to commit, but not what I want to push?** It just seems like using git through phpstorm is more of a hassle than it is a useful feature at the current time. Do I need to create new local branch every time I plan on doing any project, regardless of the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new local branch, e.g. `stable`, representing what you want to push:

```
git branch stable
```

[`merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) branches into this, or [`cherry-pick` individual commits](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), as required:

```
git checkout stable
git merge feature-1
git merge master
git cherry-pick 1234abc
```

`push` that branch to your remote:

```
git checkout stable
git push origin stable
```

It is important to test your changes together before pushing to your remote, so you can be sure that the set of changes you're making are compatible.

Therefore it might be a good idea to merge `stable` into your other branches, e.g. `feature-1` and `master`, testing there, and then merging back into `stable`, which should now give you a fast-forward merge. You may also want to consider [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for this.

Some teams [use `master` as their stable branch](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), while others use it for active development.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **documentation** form **phpStorm**'s **JetBrain**:

> ### To cherry pick changes between two branches
>
> 1. **Switch to the target branch** that the changes will be integrated
>      to.
> 2. Open the **Version Control** tool window and switch to the **Log** tab.
> 3. From the **Branch** drop-down list on the toolbar, select the source
>      branch containing the changes you want to cherry-pick. Note that the
>      **Commits pane** lists all commits performed in the selected branch. To
>      reduce the number of items in the list, you can filter the commits
>      by the user or date. You can also click the **Highlight non-picked
>      commits** button to grey out the commits that have already been
>      applied to the current branch.
> 4. Select the required commit. Use the information in the **Commit
>      Details area** if necessary.
> 5. Click the **Cherry-pick** button on the toolbar. IntelliJ IDEA will
>      display the **Commit Changes** dialog with the automatically generated
>      commit message.
> 6. If you want to review the changes or even modify the code before
>      committing it to the target branch, you can do so in the difference
>      viewer available from this dialog.
> 7. When done, click **Commit** to cherry-pick the selected changes.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/applying-changes-from-a-specific-commit-to-other-branches-cherry-picking.html?origin=old_help